# Why does console.log("text") return string in two lines when just "text" returns a single line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to retrive the text within an element and turn it into a key-value pair to be stored in an object. I used element.innerText to get the text values from the var element.

The var element

```
<div class="vorto" id="v0">
  <h3><strong>prepozicio</strong> 
    (prepozici·o)
  </h3>
<div id="en34737">preposition</div></div>
```

the word I want to set as Key is in strong tag, and the value I want to set is in the inner div tag.
The words in the parentheses should be part of the Key value, but sometimes the element does not have it.

And I notice something strange when I used console.log("text") versus just putting in "text" into the console.

Here is what console.log gives me

```
console.log(text)
prepozicio (prepozici·o)
preposition
```

And here is text

```
text
"prepozicio (prepozici·o) preposition"
```

I want to break the string up into the format displayed like what console.log display, namely the first line as the key and the second line as the value.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you have set a variable ```text``` to equal the string "prepozicio (prepozici·o) preposition"? If you want name/value pairs, you should instantiate an object, e.g. ```var text = { prepozicio: "preposition"}``` or something.

Comment: show full code - it does not seem to behave like ou described: https://jsfiddle.net/jxshjtx0/

Comment: there is definitely a newline character in the string somewhere (`\n`) - see if it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a return '\n' in the text, which console.log displays.  If you want to create a key-value pair from the text, there are a few different ways to do so.

If you want the first word to be the key, use

```
var ary = text.split(' ');
```

this will give you an array of words like so

```
["prepozicio", "(prepozici·o)", "preposition"];
```

You could use a function and object literals to make an object with an arbitrary key-value.

```
function makeExample(text) {
  var key = text[0];
  var value = text.slice(1).join(" ")
  var obj = {};
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj
}

var example = makeExample(text);
example.prepozicio;
=> "(prepozici·o) preposition"
```

If you want to transform the text in a particular way, you can read about JavaScript string operations

[MDN JavaScript String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)